# Using Epson Javascript SDK with Epson TM-20III (usb version)

Tags: javascript, sdk, thermal-printer, epson, printing-web-page

I've got a EPSON TM-20III POS printer that I'm using for some project I'm working on. I'm trying to print receipts from the front end (back end is not an option at this moment) so I got to know about the Epson Javascript SDK. According to their documentation, the printer is supported by the SDK, but when going through the methods, the one that's suppose to create the connection to the printer is the following:

`connect(ipAddress, port, callback, options);`

In which `ipAddress` *Specifies the IP address of the printer.*. The problem is that my model has no ethernet port, therefore (I guess) it won't have an IP address.

Here's the method's documentation: https://download4.epson.biz/sec_pubs/pos/reference_en/epos_js/ref_epos_sdk_js_en_eposdeviceobject_connectmethod.html#i893740

Anyone who's faced the same issue knows if it's possible to get around it? or there's simply no way to use their SDK with an USB printer? I tried to reach EPSON's customer service but never got an answer.

Thanks

Comment: This help article is in Japanese language, but it appears that the ePOS SDK for JavaScript does not support printing to printers connected via USB or Bluetooth. [USB , Bluetooth 接続での ePOS SDK for JavaScript 使用について](https://faq2.epson.jp/web/Detail.aspx?id=50284) Please check with translation services on the web.